# R apply result is inconsistent

Tags: r

I call `apply` to apply a function over a each row of my dataframe, however I am getting some strange results. When I first run `apply` (run #1), only a subset of the rows produce the expected result. After running `apply` a second time (run #2), some of the value that were initially incorrect are correct. It is consistent in which rows are incorrect after run #1.

`assign_id()` looks for the ID located in `first` with the nine other columns within the dataframe, returning an integer corresponding to the column that matches.

```
assign_id <- function(row) {
  if(is.na(row['first'])) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% c('none')) {
    return(0)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['one'])){
    return(1)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['two'])){
    return(2)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['three'])){
    return(3)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['four'])){
    return(4)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['five'])){
    return(5)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['six'])){
    return(6)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['seven'])){
    return(7)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['eight'])){
    return(8)
  }
  else if(row['first'] %in% as.character(row['nine'])){
    return(9)
  } else {
    return(11)
  }
}

df <- read.csv('df.csv')

# Run #1
df$id <- apply(df, 1, assign_id)
# All 'id' fields return 11
df[df$first %in% 55627, c('id', 'first', 'six')] 

> head(df[df$first %in% 55627, c('id', 'first', 'six')])
     id first    six
414  11 55627  55627
529  11 55627 118950
791  11 55627  55627
1570 11 55627 118950
1832 11 55627 118950
2116 11 55627 118950

# Run #2
df$id <- apply(df, 1, assign_id)
# All 'id' fields return the correct integer
df[df$first %in% 55627, c('id', 'first', 'six')] 

> head(df[df$first %in% 55627, c('id', 'first', 'six')])
     id first    six
414   6 55627  55627
529   5 55627 118950
791   6 55627  55627
1570  8 55627 118950
1832  5 55627 118950
2116  5 55627 118950
```

Data is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jsb8ost4y64iuyZKKacDEGoPsIvSiL0n/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior that you are with this example. Side note: are you sure you want to be returning NULLs from that function? I think you might have meant NA. NULLs would typically mean that the result will remain as a list, not a vector, and if you unlist it, the NULLs will be dropped entirely, shortening the vector's length.

Comment: Thanks @joran, do you get the result from Run #2 upon running `apply()` once? When I change `return(NULL)` to `return(NA)` in the first if condition, the results from runs #1 and #2 are the same, but both incorrect.

Comment: As an alternative to `apply` you can use `dplyr::case_when` which is also vectorized.

Comment: Thanks, a combination of `dplyr::case_when()` and `mutate()` seems to work. I'm still puzzled by why the original function doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from [friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501292/inconsistent-results-in-apply#55501418), I came up with this simpler, base-R solution:

```
df$id<-unlist(apply(df,1,function(x)
  ifelse(x["first"]=="none",0, which(as.integer(x["first"])==as.integer(x[2:10])))))
```

See the answers there for an explanation of why `apply` was problematic -- briefly, it transformed all your data to character, but then padded it in a way that made the comparisons fail.

On a related note, when you `read.csv`, you might want to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to avoid making the `first` column a factor.

Comment: Or `mapply(match, dd[[1]], split(dd[-1], 1:nrow(dd)))`? (I am using dd from the q&a you linked.)

Comment: Yes, but mine is substantially faster: Unit: seconds
  expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq
   iod  4.141213  4.141213  4.154136  4.154136  4.16706
 frank 22.220058 22.220058 23.398411 23.398411 24.57676
      max neval
  4.16706     2
 24.57676     2
(I only ran it twice because at over 20 seconds per round for your solution, it would have taken half an hour to run it the default 100 times)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it's the `split` that's making it slow. Another variant would be `library(data.table); setDT(dd)[, first_match := names(.SD)[mapply(match, first, transpose(.SD))], .SDcols=!"first"]` so transpose is used instead of split. In any case, if the OP had better-structured data, I'm sure even faster approaches than yours could be used. (`apply` on a dataframe is always costly.)

Comment: Yes, well, data.table is always faster - I should really take the time to figure it out... And true about the data structure, but I take that as a given.